# Can I have javascript search for a string in my web page and delete the span it belongs to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Specifically, I'll have a bunch of span classes without names and I only want the script to delete the spans that contain the text `"Test"` in them after the page has loaded.

```
<span class=""></span>

<span class=""></span>

<span class="">Test</span> //<- Delete this one!

<span class=""></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will help you.

Javascript

```
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span') // fetch all the span elements
spans.forEach((node) => {
   if(node.innerHTML === 'Test') {
     node.remove()  // at your condition remove the element from DOM
   }
});
```

jQuery

```
$('span:contains("Test")').remove()
```

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/sibabrat_swain/pen/mdVVOpP)

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, only need 1 line.

```js
$('span:contains("Test")').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="">1</span>

<span class="">2</span>

<span class="">Test</span>

<span class="">3</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery `.each()` loop on the target element list... Then use `.remove()`
 on the `this` instance of the looped element if conditional is true.

```js
let $span = $('span');
$span.each(function() {
  if($(this).text() === "Test"){
     $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="">Other text</span>

<span class="">Other text</span>

<span class="">Test</span> <!-- Delete this one! -->

<span class="">Other text</span>
```